# RSclient use local variable in eval

Tags: rserve

if suppose I have an local variable input <- 100 Can You suggest me How to use the local varaibles in RS.eval(c1,xx <-input) please comment

Comment: use `substitute` and `RS.eval(..., lazy=FALSE)`.